# unexpected GET request on karma unit testing

Tags: phantomjs, karma-jasmine, httpbackend, angular-mock

I am using karma to test a controller in my angular app, the app it self works as expected but unit test throws `error: unexpected request: GET views/home.html`
as I got the problem is by ui-router and $httpBackend. so one approach was caching by ‘karma-preprocessor’ but what I have done is:

```
var MenuController, scope, $httpBackend;
// Initialize the controller and a mock scope
beforeEach(inject(function($controller, _$httpBackend_, $rootScope, menuService) {
// place here mocked dependencies
$httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
$httpBackend.whenGET("views/header.html").respond(200,'');
$httpBackend.expectGET("http://localhost:3000/dishes").respond([{ ....
```

but the GET error shows for every template in my views folder.

**NOW is there any way to ignore all templates and any other unexpected GET requests?**

Answer (score 1):

You can create a regular expression that matches all the templates requests:
`httpBackend.whenGET(/views\/.*\.html/).respond(200, {});` or only
`httpBackend.whenGET(/views\//).respond(200, {})`